# Few conditions in mongodb Query

Tags: mongodb

my mongo document looks that:

```
{  "moods" : [  "angry",  "furious" ], 
"genres" : [  "rock",  "metal" ] }
```

and I'm sending two parameters, string(mood) and array(genres)

```
mood = "angry"
genres = ["rock, "rap"]
```

Now i want to query ma database for documents, which has my mood in moods array and has ANY of genre from my genres array. I've tried it this way:

```
    collection.find(
            { $and:[
            { 'moods' : { $in : [ mood ] }}, 
            {'genres' : { $in : genres}}
            ]})
```

but it doesnt work, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Missing a double quote after rock

```
genres = ["rock, "rap"]
```

should be

```
genres = ["rock", "rap"]
```